# Python + .Net Core это возможно?

Tags: python, .net

Можно ли прикрутить функциональность Питона к бэкэнду веб-приложения .Net.
Ну то есть, например, по нажатию кнопки запускается веб-парсинг с заданными параметрами.

Comment: Просто запустите дочерний python-процесс да и всё, не?

Comment: А если "дочерний python-процесс" это несколько больших взаимно ссылающихся файлов + пользовательский ввод? Ну т.е. там почти всё можно сделать на c#, но не хочется.

Comment: А как это мешает?

Comment: 'Как это мешает' - пока не знаю, ни разу так не делал. Такая практика это вообще норм или так делать не принято?

Comment: Можно отдельный веб сервис на python написать, который будет вызываться из вашего веб-приложения. Тогда вообще не будут нужны какие-то специализированные средства для взаимодействия с python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно встроить python в .Net при помощи https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PythonEngine.Initialize();
    using (Py.GIL())
    {
        dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
        Console.WriteLine(np.cos(np.pi * 2));

        dynamic sin = np.sin;
        Console.WriteLine(sin(5));

        double c = (double)(np.cos(5) + sin(5));
        Console.WriteLine(c);

        dynamic a = np.array(new List<float> { 1, 2, 3 });
        Console.WriteLine(a.dtype);

        dynamic b = np.array(new List<float> { 6, 5, 4 }, dtype: np.int32);
        Console.WriteLine(b.dtype);

        Console.WriteLine(a * b);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

результат:

```
1.0
-0.958924274663
-0.6752620892
float64
int32
[  6.  10.  12.]
```